# Central Login for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an app that is already in production and now I have implemented a chat based on Firebase.

Because I have all the users already authenticated in my system I am currently logging in into Firebase using only one email account, so all sessions for all users share the same Firebase login, based on email and password.

Although it works I don't think this is the best solution for my system.
How should I approach the Firebase login in this case? What is the best and most secure solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could add your existing login-system as authentication provider.
Your server backend would [create a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens) and return it to the user if he successfully signed in. The user can then pass that token to `signInWithCustomToken()` to authenticate against firebase.